# best way to find top-level directory for path in bash

Tags: bash

I need a command that will return the top level base directory for a specified path in bash.

I have an approach that works, but seems ugly:

```
echo "/go/src/github.myco.com/viper-ace/psn-router" | cut -d "/" -f 2 | xargs printf "/%s"
```

It seems there is a better way, however all the alternatives I've seen seem worse.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I updated to prefix with a "/"

Comment: For `cut`, you can just use `-f-2`.

Comment: yes base dir is probably a better term in this case.  updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is using `awk`:

```
echo "/go/src/github.myco.com/viper-ace/psn-router" |
awk -F/ '{print FS $2}'
```

```
/go
```

Comment: thanks, I think this is both short and readable.  definitely nicer than my solution

Answer (score 2):

As a native-bash approach forking no subshells and invoking no other programs (thus, written to minimize overhead), which works correctly in corner cases *including* directories with newlines:

```
topdir() {
    local re='^(/+[^/]+)'
    [[ $1 =~ $re ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
}
```

Like most other solutions here, invocation will then look something like `outvar=$(topdir "$path")`.

---

To minimize overhead even further, you could pass in the destination variable name rather than capturing stdout:

```
topdir() {
    local re='^(/+[^/]+)'
    [[ $1 =~ $re ]] && printf -v "$2" '%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
}
```

...used as: `topdir "$path" outvar`, after which `"$outvar"` will expand to the result.

Answer (score 1):

not sure better but with `sed`

```
$ echo "/go/src/github.myco.com/viper-ace/psn-router" | sed -E 's_(/[^/]+).*_\1_'
/go
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed possibility. Still ugly. Handles things like `////////home/path/to/dir`. Still blows up on newlines.

```
$ echo "////home/path/to/dir" | sed 's!/*\([^/]*\).*!\1!g'
/home
```

Newlines breaking it:

```
$ cd 'testing '$'\n''this' 
$ pwd
/home/path/testing
this
$ pwd | sed 's!/*\([^/]*\).*!/\1!g'
/home
/this
```

If you know your directories will be rather normally named, your and anubhava's solutions certainly seem to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is bash, sed and tr in a function :

```
#!/bin/bash




function topdir(){
  dir=$( echo "$1" | tr '\n' '_' )
  echo "$dir" | sed -e 's#^\(/[^/]*\)\(.*\)$#\1#g'
}



topdir '/go/src/github.com/somedude/someapp'

topdir '/home/somedude'

topdir '/with spaces/more here/app.js'

topdir '/with newline'$'\n''before/somedir/somefile.txt'
```

Regards!

Comment: You are correct. Editing